# Microservices: How to migrate data between multiple microservices?

Tags: architecture, migration, microservices, bounded-contexts

Perhaps we have such a group of microservices:
[image]
Users service and Products service is some services with their own business logic. Templates service is a service that responds to fill some templates according to complex logic( for example,  templates of emails that should be sent to a user, etc,). So, it stores the template itself, and general information used for all templates ( accesses, styles, and many more). **So it's a template engine, but it's not responsible for content of a template it should fill**.
For example, we have the next template:  HelloWorldTemplate: "Hello, world! my name is {UserName}".
When the user service needs to send an email, he asks Templates service to fill these templates by making the request with the type (HelloWorldTemplate) and template specific parameters (UserName).
The templates service is responsible for styles and general parameters.
Sorry for such a long introduction)

We develop some new functionality in Users service, and we need a new template, BirthdayGreeting, from the Templates service.
So when we upgrade UserService from v1.1 to v1.2 we need to change the internal state of another service, Templates. And how to do it - it's my main question.

I can imagine several ways to do it, but all of them have multiple drawbacks. ( Let's think that all services have SQL databases, it simplifies the problem)

---

1.We can update Templates service before updating the Users services, and add SQL migration in this service, where we can simply INSERT needed data in the tables.

**Pros**:

- Very easy to implement
- It works)

**Cons**:

- We have to give access to Template service repo to the team, that develops User service ( and also they have to know the internal DB structure of Templates, which is bad), or we have to create a separate task for the team who develops Templates service to add a new template.

---

2.We can access the Templates database from other services, and commit
    DB migration scripts to, for example, Users service repo.

**Pros:**

- Still simple to implement
- We do not have to give access to Template services repo to other teams.

**Cons:**

- We have to have a connection to the template database from multiple services, that brokes encapsulation.
- The same as for the first option.

---

3.We can add HTTP endpoint to add a new template to Templates service, and Users service should execute one(or many) requests against this endpoint during migration from v1.1 to v1.2, along with running his own DB migrations.

**Pros:**

- We can keep the consistency of the data ( Templates can run some validations on these requests to prevent invalid data)
- We do not expose the internal structure of Templates service to the world ( so we can easily switch from SQL DB to another type of DB, for example)
- These migrations will be stored in Users service, and the team that develops this service will write and maintaining them, so we can reduce cross-team communication and reduce feature delivery time.

**Cons:**

- Hard to implement.
- How to store and write this request? We can use existing requests format ( CURL, Postman requests and so on, but it can be much more verbose than simple SQL DML statement). Also, we can create own request definition language, using yaml, json or another markup language, but it looks like creating own wheel ;)
  Hard to support transactions ( for example, if migration from v1.1 to v1.2 fails, it's hard to rollback changes)

---

**So, I'll be very grateful for any advice, useful links, patterns, and best practices intended to solve this problem.**

Comment: Your question isn't related to programming and should be closed as such, Basically you have issue with distributing tasks between teams. The first approach is the correct one, in terms of safest deployment. If there is a team that is responsible for a microservice, you give that team the task that will change it, even if it's DB migration. If there are two microservices, there should be two tasks for two teams. Your feature isn't decomposed to tasks enough if you have troubles with giving a task to other team.

Comment: Do they actually all have SQL databases (or a relational database), or was using a database as a store for templates just for illustrative purposes?